# Is there a Sip code for number not in service?

Tags: asterisk, sip

I'm trying to implement a SIP client for a Call Center software based on asterisk. Is there any SIP Code in response when I call a number that is not in service? Or another way to recognize it from a SIP session message?

Comment: Please check RFC 3261, it's all in there

Comment: Assuming the number is "permanently" out of service: I would advise to use "410 Gone". "503" should be used only when the service don't know why it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if this code exist or not.

Most provider not care and return 503 for any case when they can't deliver call.

You can check for your provider by enable SIP debug and test.